# Conflict found in Assemblies - azure cosmosdb assemblies

Tags: c#, azure, assemblies

I am new to C# and been assigned a project based on Azure CosmosDB.
I am trying to develop an MVC and integrate it with Azure CosmosDB. 
I am getting this below error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/sss/source/repos/StorageAspNet/StorageAspNet/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\sss\source\repos\StorageAspNet\StorageAspNet\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\sss\source\repos\StorageAspNet\StorageAspNet\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\sss\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sss/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/e10709d8/d578a8f8/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sss/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/e10709d8/d578a8f8/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/sss/source/repos/StorageAspNet/StorageAspNet/bin/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

But there is some conflict between assembly that I have installed. I am not sure what is the issue so I have posted the above log.

I am also getting this warning below, which I think is reason of the error I am getting while running the application.

```
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.  StorageAspNet
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by updating `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` to a version `1.20` or later.  It looks like there may be an issue with the nuspec for `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` in that it only specifies version >= `1.19.0` for `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` but it really needs a later version.  For me it only picked up version `1.19.1` which resulted in the same error as you are seeing.